# Docusign esignature rest api structure error - no recipient could be found

Tags: api, docusignapi

Getting below error in structure when trying  to send doc in base 64 json format from SAP to Docusign

When the type is Json
{"errorCode":"RECIPIENTS_NOT_PROVIDED","message":"No recipients were found in the request."}

Answer (score 0):

Not much information in this question, but this error message suggests that maybe the entire envelope definition was updated and you need to have one or more recipient(s) in the request body.
Please check which endpoint you are calling in the API and ensure you provide all the needed information in the body.
If you provide your code - we can provide better answers.